# An incompatible version of Kotlin in React native project

Tags: react-native

I am facing this issue when I try to run react native project in android

**/Users/sai/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.3-all/6en3ugtfdg5xnpx44z4qbwgas/gradle-8.3/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.**

I am trying to fix it from many days but I am not able to find any solution. If someone knows how to solve it then please let me know. Thank you

Current version of kotlin in my project in build.gradle file is:
kotlinVersion = '1.8.10'

I have tried to change it to 1.9.0, but still it does not work

Comment: same here, I'm loosing my mind. any solutions?